# Is there an API to get Google Meet attendance report?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, server, google-analytics, google-api, google-meet

There is [attendance tracking feature](https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10090454?hl=en) in Google Meet for business accounts that can be turned on in the settings and Google emails the report after the meeting ends. I want to know if an API is available to get the attendance report programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Attendance tracking is available in **google workspace business plus or higher plans** and now the api is also available with which you can get a lot of details but business plus or higher account is a pre-requisite.
Check the api documentation for more:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/overview

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30171367)